Multilabel Classification - Flat Binary Classifiers vs Hierarchical Binary Classifiers
Was researching on multi label classification to solve the problem of tagging news articles with topics and countries, where tags follow the syntax <topic>-<country>, and would like to weigh multiple binary classifier options (flat vs hierarchical classification).
Approach 1 (flat classification) builds 1 model per tag. The model learns the dependence within 1 tag (i.e. between topic and country), but not the dependence between tags.
Approach 2 (hierarchical classification) builds topic model (parent) and subsequently country models (children). The benefit of this approach is that it accounts for hierarchical information so dependence between tags is retained, but at the cost of error from parent propagating to the child, and complexities in measuring performance of hierarchical classifiers. It also assumes that the concept of topic remains the same for various countries.
Wanted to ask what other factors that would lead one to choose one approach over another, and why?

Experiment both approach and compare; let the result speak for itself.
